# Minimising number of tests in COVID Pool Testing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I know there's been a good amount written on COVID-19 pool testing, but I think my question is slightly different.

Suppose your PCR machine can pool a maximum of 32 samples and test it. If you know that there are two sick people in a group of 1000 people, what's the minimum number of tests that can be done, given that each test must be made beforehand?

What I mean by "made beforehand" is that each pool to be tested is independent of each prior test.

Comment: This is problem #5 from the [2021 Mathcamp qualifying quiz](https://www.mathcamp.org/qualifying_quiz/current_quiz/), for which the deadline is March 18th. Posting it here is against the MSE contest problem policy, and also against the rules for the qualifying quiz.